# How to store array of objects in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have this form

```
<shipping-rules-form>
    <div class="row" v-for="(input,index) in form.inputs" :key="index" style="align-items: center;">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
                        <label>Lower Bound</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lower_bound" v-model="input.lower_bound" class="form-control" placeholder="Upper Bound">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
                        <label>Upper Bound</label>
                        <input type="text" name="upper_bound" v-model="input.upper_bound" class="form-control" placeholder="Lower Bound">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
                        <label>Price</label>
                        <input type="text" name="price" v-model="input.price" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="font-size: 30px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="addInput"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="removeInput" v-show="form.inputs.length > 1"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
</shipping-rules-form>
```

and my .js file have this

```
import AppForm from '../app-components/Form/AppForm';
Vue.component('shipping-rules-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    props:['cities','countries'],
    data: function() {
        return {
                inputs: [
                    {
                        lower_bound:'',
                        upper_bound:'',
                        price:'',
                    }
                ],
  
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addInput(){
            this.form.inputs.push({lower_bound:'',upper_bound:'',price:''});
        },
        removeInput(index){
            this.form.inputs.splice(index, 1);
        },
    },
    computed:{
        elements()
        {
            if(this.form.shippable_type == 1) {
                return this.countries;
            } else {
                return this.cities;
            }
        },

    }

});
```

I wanted to store that inputs (array of object) as a json

In my controller I have done this

```
$json = $request->input('inputs');
```

But $json is return null .

I am getting all other data correctly only this is returning null.

I have tried purely with html and laravel too without using vue component but it is returning me null .

Comment: If you do `$request->all() `you can see it?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form you can pass the named value as lower_bound and upper_bound but in the controller you can access input thats why you $json variable show null value. You can use name as array name="lower_bound[]" same as upper_bound and in the controller you cam access the value simple by index number $json = $request->lower_bound[0];